# Invalid comparator

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Почему данный код бросает исключение Invalid comparator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class StrCmp
{
public:
    template <typename T> bool operator()
        (const T* p1, const T* p2) const
    {
        while (*p1 && *p2 && *p1 == *p2)
            ++p1, ++p2;

        return *p2 - *p1 > 0;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    const unsigned int* a[]
    {
        (const unsigned int*)"Сидоров",
        (const unsigned int*)"Петров",
        (const unsigned int*)"Иванов",
        (const unsigned int*)"Аров",
        (const unsigned int*)"Аро",
        (const unsigned int*)"",
    };

    std::sort(a, a + 6, StrCmp() );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В данном случае все просто - у вас сравниваются беззнаковые величины, и `*p2 - *p1` **всегда** больше нуля. По беззнаковости :)

А Visual C++ в отладочном режиме проверяет компаратор, сравнивая два вызова - типа `comp(a,b)` и `comp(b,a)`, и если они оба оказываются истинны - он справедливо полагает компаратор некорректным.

Ибо не может одновременно быть `a < b` и `b < a`. Исправьте свой компаратор, чтобы он давал **правильные** результаты...

P.S. Выполните [такой код](https://ideone.com/zhcYsV):

```
std::cout << StrCmp()(a[2],a[5]) << std::endl;
std::cout << StrCmp()(a[5],a[2]) << std::endl;
```

Вывод будет - две единицы. Т.е. и `a[2] < a[5]`, и `a[5] < a[2]` - так говорит ваш компаратор.

Но так не бывает, и VC++ (в отладочном режиме) сообщает вам о том, что ваш компаратор никуда не годится. Потому что сравнение `a` с `b` дает тот же результат, что и `b` с `a`...

Comment: одним словом все неправильно...

Comment: @AnT А, да, тут я погорячился...

Comment: @Harry как что что то может быть одновременно и меньше и больше

Comment: Вот! Никак. А у вас ваш компаратор дает одновременно и больше, и меньше! См. дополненный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

При переинтерпретации обыкноенной строки `char []` с единственным `\0` в конце как массива `unsigned int []` нет практически никаких шансов на то, что в конце такого массива `unsigned int []` вы увидите  завершающий `0`. То есть если ваш цикл сравнения не найдет различий, то такой цикл не будет останавливаться в конце строки, а  будет выходить за пределы доступной памяти и сравнивать неинициализированные и/или нестабильные значения. Сравнение нестабильных значений ведет к нестабильным и/или несогласованным результатам сравнения, что ведет к неопределенному поведению, в т.ч. выбросу такого исключения.

Переинтерпретация памяти - это почти всегда грязный хак. Но если уж вы хотите сравнивать ваши строки именно так, то вам надо гарантировать, что в конце каждой строки будет присутствовать нулевое значение типа `unsigned int`. Например, при `sizeof(unsigned int) == 4` ваши строки должны выглядеть как

```
const unsigned int* a[]
{
    (const unsigned int*)"Сидоров\0\0\0\0\0\0",
    (const unsigned int*)"Петров\0\0\0\0\0\0",
    (const unsigned int*)"Иванов\0\0\0\0\0\0",
    (const unsigned int*)"Аров\0\0\0\0\0\0",
    (const unsigned int*)"Аро\0\0\0\0\0\0",
    (const unsigned int*)"\0\0\0\0\0\0",
};
```

Т.е. в общем случае (не подстраиваясь под длину конкретной строки) вам нужно как минимум 7 нулей в конце строки, чтобы гарантировать, что переинтерпретация этой строки как `unsigned int []` обязательно найдет в конце нулевое значение.

Comment: почему будет выходить за пределы доступной памяти

Comment: @Stanislav: Вы переинтерпретируете массив `char`, как массив `unsigned int`. На "обычных" платформах `unsigned int` больше по размеру, чем `char`. В конце исходного массива `char` стоит одинокий `char` равный `0`. Но шансов на то, что там каким-то чудом окажется целый `unsigned int`, равный `0` очень мало. По этой причине при равенстве исходных массивов строк ваш цикл практически никогда не будет завершаться, а будет вылетать за пределы массива и там накрываться медным тазом. Напр.: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83662a1d1a5a88ab